# Autolayout on macOS: hide control when window size below threshold

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout, interface-builder

I have a macOS app window for a music player with a few controls and a playlist - NSTableView. I'd like to automatically hide the playlist when the window is resized below a certain threshold.

Can I achieve this with autolayout alone (something like "install" options/size classes on iOS) or do I have to write code to listen to window resize events, evaluate the size and hide the playlist manually?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it with auto layout alone.

If you use an `NSSplitViewController`, and you set the `behavior` of the `NSSplitViewItem` containing the table view to `NSSplitViewItemBehaviorSidebar` (Swift: `NSSplitViewItem.Behavior.sidebar`), and you set the split view controller's `minimumThicknessForInlineSidebars` to the minimum desired width of the table view, then the split view controller will take care of hiding the sidebar when the window becomes too narrow.

Look at [*Exhibition: An Adaptive OS X App*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Exhibition/Listings/Exhibition_GalleryWindowController_swift.html) for an example. This is the key section in `GalleryWindowController.swift`:

```
    splitViewController.minimumThicknessForInlineSidebars = 992.0
    splitViewController.view.wantsLayer = true

    // Create a sidebar SplitViewItem. This has metrics and behaves like system standard sidebars.
    let sidebarSplitViewItem = NSSplitViewItem(sidebarWithViewController: self.sidebarController)
    splitViewController.addSplitViewItem(sidebarSplitViewItem)
```